# Alterar Cor da string mediante ao retorno do Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho o código abaixo, caso a coluna score tiver um campo com "LOW" a cor de apenas o LOW tem que ser (#FFFF00) e se caso o campo for HIGHT, apenas o HIGHT tem que ter a cor (#FF0000):

```
   <?php  
    while($row = $stm->fetch())  {
    $color = $row["score"];

   echo "<tr>"."<td><input type=checkbox name='check[]' value='[]' ></td>"."</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .$row['quantidade']. "</td><td>". "<font size='1'>". $row['data'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" . $row['ip'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" . $row['hostname'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .$row['sender']. "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .$row['subject']."</td><td>"."<font size='1'>"."<div id=add9 align=middle style='color: {$color}; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 1px darkblue'>" .$row['score']. " <td><a href=delete.php?id=". $row['id'] . " data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' </a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p>
</tr>".'' ;
}

  switch($color){

    case 'LOW':
        $color = "#FFFF00";
        break;
    case 'HIGH':
        $color = "#FF0000";
        break;  

        return $color;
}




 ?>
```

O que ocorre que nenhuma cor é alterada no campo que tem estes cases. Poderiam me ajudar onde estou errando?

Grato.

Comment: Você pretende diferenciar as linhas de forma sequencial ? preto-branco-preto-branco-preto-branco, ou variar dependendo desse campo ?

Comment: Tenho uma coluna de score na minha pagina, e queria que conforme cada score tiver uma cor, score Higth = Vermelho, Score Low = Amarelo e Score Medium = Laranja por exemplo, apenas esses scores ter sua respectiva cor, o resto das colunas permanecem com a cor padrão que é preto.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui observar dois possíveis problemas:

1º Seu Switch deve estar antes do seu echo, tente criar uma função e chamar ela dentro do laço, abaixo um exemple de como você pode estruturar:

```
<?php  
function GetColor($color){
  switch($color){
    case 'LOW':
        $color = "#FFFF00";
        break;
    case 'HIGH':
        $color = "#FF0000";
        break;  
    }
    return $color;
}

while($row = $stm->fetch())  {
    $color = $row["score"];

   echo "<tr>"."<td><input type=checkbox name='check[]' value='[]' ></td>"."</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .
   $row['quantidade']. "</td><td>". "<font size='1'>". 
   $row['data'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" . 
   $row['ip'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" . 
   $row['hostname'] . "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .
   $row['sender']. "</td><td>"."<font size='1'>" .
   $row['subject']."</td><td>"."<font size='1'>".
   "<div id=add9 align=middle style='color: " . GetColor($color)."; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 1px darkblue'>" .
   $row['score']. "</div></td><td><a href=delete.php?id=". $row['id'] . " data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' </a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p></td>
</tr>".'' ;
}
?>
```

2º Sua atribuição css ao color parece incorreta:

tente assim

```
color: ".$color.";
```

Comment: Fiz estas alterações sugeridas @Ricardo, porem não gera nenhum erro, porem as cores não alteram, continuam com o default (preto).

Comment: Caso você precise alterar a cor de todos os itens da linha, chame a função na tag TR também:

<tr style='color: " . GetColor($color).";' >

Comment: preciso apenas da palavra (Hight ou Medium ou Low) que tenha a cor alterada, o restante permanece com o padrão.

Comment: Achei outro probleminha, altere a cor que está {##FFFF00} para {#FFFF00} e feche a DIV que ficou aberta na última coluna

Comment: Olá @RIcardo, o ## foi no copy&paste, no meu codigo está correto tanto  este como o fechamento da div , ta fechado aqui ===> darkblue'>" .

Comment: Tente colocar então o !important  `color: " . GetColor($color)." !important;`

Se não funcionar, você pode tentar isolar essa saída em uma tag span, ou então tente debugar pelo navegador, para ver se está sendo atribuída a cor corretamente no elemento html

Comment: Após executar a página, e olhando o codigo fonte, o campo "Color" está vazio, veja:    <td><font size='1'><span style='color: '> HIGH <td>. Saberia o motivo?

Comment: Provavelmente ele não entrou em nenhum case, faça o teste colocando um valor default
`switch($color){
    case 'LOW':
        $color = "#FFFF00";
        break;
    case 'HIGH':
        $color = "#FF0000";
        break; 
        default:
        $color = "red"; 
    }
`

Comment: Se eu colocar o default, ele pega : <span style='color: red', porem se eu remover o default ele pega o valor da variavel color : <font size='1'><span style='color:  HIGH'> . Muito estranho!